# How to react by hover with dynamically added class?

Tags: jquery, class, dynamic, scroll, hover

The class **sticked** is adding when you scroll on top. If you scroll far many small miniatures are appearing to right. So there are two questions:

1. Why not all element react on hover by adding class **test**?
2. How to add class **test** on next **sticked** class?

[The link on example.](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/PPyjqX)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

  $('.text-layer').each(function(i) {

    $window = $(window);
    var increase = i * 50
    var newHeight = $(".text-layer").outerHeight();
    var newWidth = $(".text-layer").outerWidth();
    var distance = $(this).parent().offset().top + newHeight

    if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {
      $(this).addClass('sticked').css("transform", "translate(100%," + increase + "px) scale(.8)");
      $(this).parent().css({"height": newHeight, "width": newWidth });
      checkit()
    }

    if ($window.scrollTop() <= distance) {
      $(this).removeClass('sticked').css("transform", "translate(0px, 0px)");
    }
  });

});

function checkit() {
  $('.text-layer.sticked').hover(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('test')

})
}
```

Comment: You need event delegation method.

Comment: Delegate `mouseenter/mouseout` events instead

Comment: can you point me how to do this?

Comment: Look at the duplicate question, you'll understand.